# Lisp Insert an element into sublists

Tags: list, lisp, sublist

Define a function intoSublist that takes two input arguments x - atom and L - list with sublists. The function should insert x as a first element in all sublists of L.

```
(defun intoSublist (x L)
  (cond
((null L) nil)
 ((not(atom (car L)))
 (cons x (intoSublist x
L)))


(t (cons (car L) (intoSublist x
(cdr L ))))
 )
)
```

Program gives Program stack overflow. reset error. I think function is correct but i don't know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When `(not (atom (car L))` is true you cons the first element infinitely many times. Perhaps you forgot to `cdr` the argument?

Also, instead of adding in front of the list you're replacing it.